# Append a new data record to the first row of a table?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have an Ajax function to store a new record to a table. It's working but the new record will be placed to the last row of the table. How to make the new record placed to the first row of the table instead of being the last ?

Ajax function :

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-modal', function () {
        $('.modal-title').text('Add');
        $('#addModal').modal('show');
    });
    $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.add', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ URL::route('tagstore') }}',
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'title': $('#title_add').val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                if ((data.errors)) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#addModal').modal('show');
                        toastr.error('Error creating the Tag!', {timeOut: 5000});
                    }, 500);
                    if (data.errors.title) {
                        $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                    }
                } else {
                    toastr.success('Tag created succesfully!', {timeOut: 5000});
                    $('#tagTable').append(
                            "<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td class='col1'>" + data.id + "</td><td><a href='" + data.titleslug + "'>" + data.title + "<a/></td><td class='table-action'><button class='edit-modal btn btn-sm btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-sm btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></td></tr>");
                    $('.col1').each(function (index) {
                        $(this).html(index + 1);
                    });
                }
            },
        });
    });
```

The table view :

```
<table class="table table-dark mb30" id="tagTable" style="visibility: hidden";>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Tags Name</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center">Action</th>
                                </tr>
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($tags as $indexKey => $t)
                                <tr class="item{{$t->id}}">
                                    <td class="col1">{{ $indexKey+1 }}</td>
                                    <td><a href="{{ url('dashboard/tags/' . $t->titleslug) }}">{{$t->title}}</a> ({{$t->posts->count()}})</td>
                                    <td class="table-action">
                                        <button class="edit-modal btn btn-sm btn-info" data-id="{{$t->id}}" data-title="{{$t->title}}">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
                                        <button class="delete-modal btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="{{$t->id}}" data-title="{{$t->title}}">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on toastr success, try using a prepend instead of append. So that every new row is prepended instead e.g

```
$('#tagTable').prepend(...
```

Comment: I did not know about `prepend`. This solved it, thanks!